# Is there any way to hide the share and watch functionality from the player view or YouTube 3rd party player. Also long press sharing option

Tags: swift, youtube, share, swift5, youtubeplayer

I'm using [YoutubePlayerView](https://github.com/mukeshydv/YoutubePlayerView) library to play the YouTube mp4 videos and live streams.
Using this player I'm able to play YouTube content but I want to hide the three dots in right corner which shows share and watch later option, also long press copy embed and copy url, etc..

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried number of ways but still not getting the result.
Please help me to achieve that as I have to live the app on app store.

Hopping for the best.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: YouTubePlayerView is just a WKWebView. I would imagine the share buttons are part of the YouTube webpage that it is displaying so it will be unlikely you can remove them easily.